# Wordpress theme and language pack

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, po

I am building a Wordpress blog system in Spanish and I'd like to have the default theme also translated to "es_ES". I am already running this Wordpress installation in Spanish. What I'd like to know is how to do the same with the default theme (twenty-eleven).

This site allows us to download the po file with the translation: http://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp/3.2.x/twentyeleven/es/default

But I don't know what to do next...

I'd like to know the process. For I have downloaded the PO and MO files from translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp/3.2.x/twentyeleven/es/… and then uploaded them to domain.com/wp/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/languages however no change occurred...

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This post helped me to understand: http://urbangiraffe.com/articles/translating-wordpress-themes-and-plugins/

The missing information in this tuto is that the languages files must be named just like this: if wordpress is set to "es_CL", the .po and .mo files must be named es_CL.po and es_CL.mo and put in the language folder of the theme.

If the file config.php is correctly set to "es_CL" than the system will use the right language files.